# Is there a Memgraph Helm Chart out there?

Tags: memgraphdb

So far I've used Memgraph on Docker. Now I'd like to see it on K8, podman, etc. to see what works and what doesn't work.

Helm Chart seems like a good starting point, but I can't find one for Memgraph. Can someone direct me where to start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Memgraph Helmchart repository at https://github.com/memgraph/helm-charts and there is documentation at https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/deployment/kubernetes.